# How to optimize code to calculate rolling calculations in a dataframe fast?

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

This code reads through each value in `fnoStocks` dataframe and for each file it is reading the file and calculating some metrics.

Each iteration of `i` is taking more than 3 minutes and I have around 156 iterations of `i`

Is it possible to optimize the inner `j` loop code so that the execution time reduces?

`i` range is from 1 to 156

`j` range is from 1 to 259

In the `WeeklyData` I am doing two rolling calculations based on lookbackPeriod and holdPeriod.

```
for(lookbackPeriod in 1:10){
  
  for(holdPeriod in 1:8){

  for (i in 1:nrow(fnoStocks)){
  
        out <- read.csv(paste("Returns\\", fnoStocks[i,1] , ".csv", sep="") )
        
        #Delete first row
        out <- out[-1,]
        
        for (j in 1:( nrow(out)-(lookbackPeriod + holdPeriod) ) ){
      
            WeeklyData <- rbind(WeeklyData,
                 data.frame(
                   StockName = fnoStocks[i,1],
                   WeekNum = j,
                   MScore = sum(out$Ret[j:(j+lookbackPeriod-1)]),
                   NWeekRet =round( 
                                  (out$Adj.Close[j+lookbackPeriod+holdPeriod-1] -
                                 out$Adj.Close[j+lookbackPeriod-1] ) / out$Adj.Close[j+lookbackPeriod-1] ,
                                 3)
                   
                 )
                )
        }
        ## j ends here
 
    }
    ## i ends here
   }}
```

What I am trying to do is this

I have Yahoo stock price data in `out` and `out$Ret` column has percentage change over last period.

Now in `WeeklyData` dataframe I am calculating values sum of Returns over the `current period + lookbackPeriod - 1` - current period is j
and I also calculating the percentage change in `out$Adj.Close` price over the `j+lookbackPeriod+holdPeriod-1` and `j+lookbackPeriod-1` that is it.

Essentially I could calculated `MScore` using rollsum function but calculating rolling percentage using `Delt` is a bit tricky since there is an offset of rows.

Comment: Instead of posting your code directly, you may create a small example of what you are trying to do so that things can be understood easily or fast alternatives suggested.  There are four nested for loops here which are things complicated.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I have added the explanation of what I am trying to do. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @AnilGoyal there are four nested loops but only the `j` inner loop is taking a lot of time, I have measured it by running partially each section.

Comment: Can you include some reproducible example too.  Without one, it is too difficult to comprehend.  Actually, I think you may make use of `runner` or `rollapply` kinda functions instead of complicating the loop.

Comment: Without seeing at least a few rows of `fnstocks` I am unable to comprehend it

Comment: Offset of rows you may tackle in `runner` package

Comment: @AnilGoyal yes I am trying to produce one minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `lapply` for the inner loop. The main reason why the inner loop is slow is because of `rbind(WeeklyData,data.frame(....))` part.

```
total_data <- vector('list', 10 * 8 * nrow(fnoStocks))
inds <- 1

for(lookbackPeriod in 1:10){
  
  for(holdPeriod in 1:8){
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(fnoStocks)){
      
      out <- read.csv(paste("Returns\\", fnoStocks[i,1] , ".csv", sep=""))
      
      #Delete first row
      out <- out[-1,]
      val <- 1:(nrow(out)-(lookbackPeriod + holdPeriod))
      do.call(rbind, lapply(val, function(j) {
        data.frame(
          StockName = fnoStocks[i,1],
          WeekNum = j,
          MScore = sum(out$Ret[j:(j+lookbackPeriod-1)]),
          NWeekRet =round( 
            (out$Adj.Close[j+lookbackPeriod+holdPeriod-1] -
               out$Adj.Close[j+lookbackPeriod-1] ) / out$Adj.Close[j+lookbackPeriod-1] ,
            3)
          
        )
      })) -> total_data[[inds]]
      inds <- inds + 1
    }
  }
}

result <- do.call(rbind, total_data)
```

Comment: do you think we can use rollsum and Delt function instead of indexing and calculating sum and percentage change i.e. MScore and NWeekRet ?

Comment: If you are performing rolling calculation, yes we can use that.

Comment: they are rolling but there is offset when we calculate percentage change which is causing the issue